# Align Image left side and Text right side with css

Tags: html, image, css, text, alignment

I have image and a text,i need the image on the left and the text on the right..
i cant change the HTML, so i need to do it with CSS only.

```
<li>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h3>
        <a href="#">title</a>
      </h3>
    </header>
    <p>
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </p>
   </article>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google first - a query for `css align image left` `css align text right` will get you the correct CSS syntax. If that doesn't solve your problem, can you clarify what you need to know? Are you unclear how to target each element?

Comment: Hi Pekka.. i tried to google it the whole day yesterday .. and its not working.. i need it to be responsive .. my title always on the top of the photo and not going right and align in the middle like i need it(i tried it with inline-block and with margin 0 auto - but with not success) .. ive tried like 20 examples but its just dont look like i need it.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use the float function and the margin function to help you with the image placement. just write your usual CSS code with `float: left` and `float : right` to help you.